# storing variables when diverting to paypal for use on return url mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, view, models

I have a mobile web app written using mvc4, I am using it to take payments through paypal, basically, I connect to the web app which is hosted on our server, I then log in, which actually logs into a server held in the work place, which returns a username, and balance etc, which I store into a model, this is fine, I can pass this through all the views, right up to the point that the app redirects to paypal, I finish off the express checkout, and all is good, but when I return to my app I would like to display the username, amount deposited and new balance, I also have to store the amount in the server using the username etc at this point, but am unable to do so, as I lose the model when it directs away ?/

is there a way to keep hold of these variables using cookies or sessions etc ?? this is my last little bit so any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie, server-side session, or server-side database to store the data under a key that is the EC token returned by the SetEC request.  Then redirect to PayPal and, on return, you'll have that same token in the Get string and can use it as a lookup.

Comment: I could, would this solution be suitable for a system that potentially has a high volume of users ?